# CodeIgniter - Pass database array from model to controller and then view

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is probably really simple, but I just started using Code Igniter.

I have the following code in a model and want to get the database query array to pass to the controller and then pass it to a page view.

```
public function view_user($id){
        $this->db->where('userid', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

What is the code necessary to get the returned array in the controller?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

here you Go with perfact answer

Model code

```
public function view_user($table,$id)
{
        $this->db->where('userid', $id);
        return $this->db->get($table);
}
```

Now in controller
Call your Method Like

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
$data['array_name']= $this->model_name->view_user('Tabelname',$id)->result();
```

If u want to Get Only single row Insted of result write ->row(); in above statement

now load your view and pass the `$data` as 2nd pararameter

```
$this->load->view('viewname',$data)
```

now in your **VIEW**

Acesss Array Like

```
  <?php foreach($array_name as $row)?>
```